# Passing command line arguments to spark submit through zeppelin web ui

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I want to configure the zeppeline spark interpreter. I would like to pass `--conf "spark.cassandra.connection.host=<ip>" --conf "spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb=32" and --jars $(echo /home/sysadmin/ApacheSpark/jar/*.jar | tr ' ' ',')` option to spark submit through my zeppelin ui interpreter.

How can I pass them?
Since I have many cassandra machines, I would like to create multiple spark interpreter and therefore do not want to add the configuration in the zeppelin-env file as stated [here.](https://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/interpreter/spark.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [inline configuration](http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.9.0-preview1/usage/interpreter/overview.html#inline-generic-configuration) to do that which is pretty easy and intuitive.

e.g.

```
%spark.conf

spark.jars. jar1,jar2
spark.cassandra.connection.host <ip>
spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb 32
```